# What's the most efficient syntax to use Merge to upsert many rows at once?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

There's 2 ways I've found of upserting many rows into a table with SQL Server 2008.

One of which is found here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx says to create a temp table, then insert values to temp table, and finally merge that table with target able.

This doesn't seem very efficient to me because you have to create a table, fill the table, merge to target table, and then delete the temp table.

The only other thing I can think of is as follows...

```
MERGE dbo.targettable as tgt
USING (
SELECT 12 as col1, 13 as col2, 'abc' as col3, 'zyx' as col4
UNION ALL
SELECT 11 as col1, 11 as col2, 'def' as col3, 'def' as col4
(etc etc)
UNION ALL
SELECT 7 as col1, 10 as col2, 'jfj' as col3, 'tub' as col4)
as new
ON tgt.col1=new.col1
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET tgt.col2=new.col2, tgt.col3=new.col3, tgt.col4=new.col4
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (col1, col2, col3, col4)
VALUES(new.col1, new.col2, new.col3, new.col4);
```

Based on usr's answer I was able to find http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

I think this is the way to do it.  Could someone verify that this syntax appears correct?

```
MERGE dbo.targettable as tgt
USING (VALUES(12, 13, 'abc', 'zyx'), (11, 11, 'def', 'def'),(7, 10, 'jfj', 'tub'))
AS new (col1, col2, col3, col4)
ON tgt.col1=new.col1
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET tgt.col2=new.col2, tgt.col3=new.col3, tgt.col4=new.col4
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (col1, col2, col3, col4)
VALUES(new.col1, new.col2, new.col3, new.col4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Where does the data to be merged come from?**

- If it comes from a query, inline the query into the merge.
- If it
  comes from the app, use table-valued parameters.
- If it is generated
  iteratively, use a temp table or table variable.
- If it is a constant like in your example use the `VALUES` clause. Don't use `UNION ALL` because it is more verbose, does not document semantics nicely and increases query compile time because the optimizer has to convert it to `VALUES` form.

Comment: Citation for don't use `UNION ALL`? As far as I've seen that gets algebrized exactly the same as `VALUES` into an internal table of constants (at least in 2008)

Comment: @MartinSmith I have seen it turn into concatenate plus one constant table per row. The query plan image is *freaking huge* then. Does not repro with the OPs sample. Still, I consider `VALUES` to be more appropriate for semantic reasons and in order to not tax the optimizer with 1000s of select clauses.

Comment: That sounds like the plan you would get for a `UNION` rather than a `UNION ALL`

Comment: Just tried with a derived table with over 1,000 `UNION ALL`s. It just shows a single table of constants but if you replace the first `UNION ALL` with a `UNION` the plan is as you describe so maybe one of them was missing an `ALL` in your case? (replacing the last `UNION ALL` with `UNION` doesn't have anywhere near as bad an effect)

Comment: Turns out it wasn't `UNION ALL` but it was `IN`. `DECLARE @i1 INT
DECLARE @i2 INT
SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id IN (@i1, @i2)`. The optimizer transformation strangely does not take here. I edited the last bullet.